# Cropping every image to a special shape in powerpoint

Tags: crop, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint premium template (attached). I don't know how, but it crops every image to a special styled shape. Any idea how can I do that in case I want to change these shapes? I have checked the master view and got nothing there too, this cropping style is a simple shape but in PowerPoint, we have no tool to draw it.

[File Link](http://www.filedropper.com/mod1lesson1)

[image: Crop style is on Left]
[image: Croped Image]

Comment: It's called masking (not cropping).  I'm not a PowerPoint user, but masking images is a common thing in graphic design applications generally. I found this link at [Office Tool Tips](https://www.officetooltips.com/powerpoint_2016/tips/how_to_make_a_mask_for_pictures_in_the_powerpoint_slide.html) if it's any help:

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a png overplayed onto the image – as png images support transparency you can create a white image with 'a hole' of the shape you want to mask.

But I think in this case they probably imported an svg, used 'Convert to Shape' and added an image into the shape.

Comment: Yeah, it is masking; thanks. Now, I can search for a relevant tool.

Answer (score 0):

So basically on your master template you add an image placeholder and the shape you want to crop it (mentioned before it can be a SVG then converted to shape). Select both and on Shape Format > Merge Shapes > Intersect. You will then have a custom shape placeholder. Hope it helps.